# Why my test ad banner is eventually showing real ads?

Tags: android, android-layout, admob

I've put an app in internal test with some collaborators and they have reported to me that my app's test ad banner is sometimes showing real ads, even though there is the black tag "Test Ad" above the real, and if someone clicks on this ad the app opens the ad's site. My concern is if there is any problem with this behaviour, and if it is, how could I correct it?

By the way I'm using (app:adSize="BANNER" app:adUnitId="bannerAdUnitId"), on all the layouts whit test ad banner.

Comment: I have always seen this behavior - I just assume if it still has the "Test Ad" banner it must be ok. If not, that's an AdMob issue...

Comment: It is completely fine. Sometimes the Real Ads' creatives are served but don't that won't generate any revenue on Impression or Ad Clicks if they are marked as `Test Ads`.

Comment: Thanks a lot both Tyler V and DarShan, you both have calmed down me, I was worried that it could generate any kind of revenue and that could get me expelled from Ad Mob!!!